# making latex table

Tags: latex, tex

Can anyone give an idea on how to make this table?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \begin{table} [...] \end{table}
Here is a minimal working example:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{l r}
                        & 119 Responses\\
    Field               & Percentage \\
    \hline
    Very convenient       & 63\% \\
    Sowewhat convenient   & 28\% \\
    Neutral               &  5\% \\
    Somewhat inconvenient &  2\% \\
    Very inconvenient     &  3\% \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]